# Initializer but incomplete type?

Tags: c++

The following code gives me 2 errors when i compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Translator.h"

using namespace std;

void Dictionary::translate(char out_s[], const char s[])
{
    int i;
    char englishWord[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];

    for (i=0;i < numEntries; i++)
    {
       if (strcmp(englishWord[i], s)==0)
           break;
    }

    if (i<numEntries)
       strcpy(out_s,elvishWord[i]);
}

char Translator::toElvish(const char elvish_line[],const char english_line[])
{
   int j=0;

    char temp_eng_words[2000][50];
    //char temp_elv_words[2000][50]; NOT SURE IF I NEED THIS

    std::string str = english_line;
    std:: istringstream stm(str);
    string word;
    while( stm >> word) // read white-space delimited tokens one by one
    {
        int k=0;
        strcpy (temp_eng_words[k],word.c_str());
        k++;
     }

     for (int i=0; i<2000;i++) // ERROR: out_s was not declared in this scope
     {
       Dictionary::translate (out_s,temp_eng_words[i]); // ERROR RELATES TO THIS LINE
      }
}

Translator::Translator(const char dictFileName[]) : dict(dictFileName)
{
    char englishWord[2000][50];
    char temp_eng_word[50];
    char temp_elv_word[50];
    char elvishWord[2000][50];
    int num_entries;

    fstream str;

    str.open(dictFileName, ios::in);
    int i;

    while (!str.fail())
    {
      for (i=0; i< 2000; i++)
      {
         str>> temp_eng_word;
         str>> temp_elv_word;
         strcpy(englishWord[i],temp_eng_word);
         strcpy(elvishWord[i],temp_elv_word);
      }

      num_entries = i;
 }

    str.close();

   }
}
```

The first one is at `std::string istringstream stm(str)`; where it says it the variable has an initializer but incomplete type. If I put in `std::string istringstream stm(str)`;  it says expected initializer before `stm` and`stm was not declared in the scope`.

It also says `out_s` was not declared in this scope at  `Dictionary::translate (out_s,temp_eng_words[i])`;. I don't see why one parameter is recognisied and one is not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your `while (stm >> word)` loop, you set `k` to zero, so each iteration is overwriting the same first `temp_eng_words[0]`.  Try executing with pen & paper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to include header file:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```

when you want to use `stringstream` and `string`.

Meanwhile:

```
Dictionary::translate (out_s,temp_eng_words[i]);
```

If `out_s` is not a member of the class, you seems forgot to define `out_s` before using it inside `toElvish`.

Meanwhile:

```
 while( stm >> word) // read white-space delimited tokens one by one
 {
    int k=0; //^^Why do you initialize k everytime you read a word?
    strcpy (temp_eng_words[k],word.c_str());
    k++;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include sstream

Answer (score 1):

Your translator would be much simpler if you used `std::map`.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

// map[english word] returns the elvish word.
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Dictionary;  

// Define the dictionary
Dictionary english_to_elvish_dictionary;


std::string To_Elvish(const std::string& english_word)
{
    Dictionary::iterator    iter;
    std::string             elvish_word;
    iter = english_to_elvish_dictionary.find(english_word);
    if (iter != english_to_elvish_dictionary.end())
    {
        // English word is in dictionary, return the elvish equivalent.
        elvish_word = *iter;
    }
    return elvish_word;
}
```

The above code fragment replaces most of your code and reduces your issues with arrays of arrays of C-strings.  Less code == less problems.

To see a list of issues your having, search StackOverflow for "[c++] elvish english".